# Anyway to get off the photos from a broken Galaxy S4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, photos, water-damage

My Galaxy S4 took a bath in the Pacific Ocean and now won't turn on. I tried to have it fixed, but it really is gone.

Is there anyway to retrieve the photos from the hard drive of the device? Assuming that it didn't get destroyed as well. If so, how???

Comment: Can you enter recovery mode by pressing vol up + home + power for a few seconds?

Comment: @PeterBartels No, the phone won't even do that.  The only thing on the phone that shows signs of life is that when I plug in the charging cable, the light at the top left lights up red.